# Artifactory based docker registry showing 404 error

Tags: linux, nginx, artifactory

I am trying to setup my first Artifactory based docker registry and I am hitting wall one after another.

So, my artifactory installation is docker-compose based and running on a Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS VM (c36l83serv01.simnetaus.local). Here is a view of my docker and postgres running:

[image: docker ps]

Docker is running on local network 192.168.0.168

I have another VM (c36l83linr01.simnetaus.local) which is hosting nginx (install using apt)
nginx version 1.18.0

here is my nginx reverse proxy setting, which was copied from Artifactory generated stub:

```
###########################################################
## this configuration was generated by JFrog Artifactory ##
###########################################################

## server configuration
server {
    
    listen 80 ;
    
    server_name c36l83linr01.simnetaus.local;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }
    ## Application specific logs
    ## access_log /var/log/nginx/c36l83linr01.simnetaus.local-access.log timing;
    ## error_log /var/log/nginx/c36l83linr01.simnetaus.local-error.log;
    rewrite ^/$ /ui/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/ui$ /ui/ redirect;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    location / {
    proxy_read_timeout  2400s;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path   ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 40 128k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
    proxy_pass          http://c36l83serv01.simnetaus.local:8082;
    proxy_set_header    X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;

        location ~ ^/artifactory/ {
            proxy_pass    http://c36l83serv01.simnetaus.local:8081;
        }
    }
}
```

My artifactory is configured for nginx as well:

[image]

[image]

I have created docker-local, docker-remote and docker (virtual) repository;

[image]

I could login to the registry from my windows command line:

[image]

However it won't allow me to push:
[image]

If I use port in the url as suggested the repo settings, I get following error:

[image]

Anyone have any clue? WHat am I doing wrong?
Any suggestion or help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should skip the /artifactory context in your docker pull and push.
404 error is basically from Nginx and not from Artifactory. As you were able to successfully login, try the below to pull,

> docker push c333333.server.name/docker-repo-name/image-name:tag

Comment: Unfortunately it gives same error.